# For each line in a file, read two integers and output the minimum

Tags: c#, beginner, programming-challenge, array

I am going through some [CodingAbbey](http://www.codeabbey.com/) problems to learn basic programming tasks, with a focus on taking input from a file, and saving to another. I have just completed [this task](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/min-of-two):

> Of two numbers, please, select one with minimum value. Here are several pairs of numbers for thorough testing.
>
> Input data will contain number of test-cases in the first line.
>   Following lines will contain a pair of numbers to compare each.
>   For Answer please enter the same amount of minimums separated by space, for example:
>
> data:
>
> ```
> 3
> 5 3
> 2 8
> 100 15
> ```
>
> answer:
>
> ```
> 3 2 15
> ```

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace cosnPrjo
{
    class MinimumOfTwo
    {

        const string inputPath = @"/Users/rs/Dropbox/InputFile.txt";
        const string outputPath = @"/Users/rs/Dropbox/OutputFile.txt";
        const string searchAfterParam = "\n";

        static void Main ()
        {
            string input = readFile (inputPath);
            input = input.Substring (input.IndexOf (searchAfterParam) + searchAfterParam.Length);
            string[] pairDelims = { "\n" };
            string[] paramDelims = { " " };
            string[] pairs = input.Split (pairDelims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string result = "";

            foreach (string pair in pairs) {
                int numToAppend = 0;
                string[] paramas = pair.Split (paramDelims, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                int firstNum = Convert.ToInt32 (paramas [0]);
                int secondNum = Convert.ToInt32 (paramas [1]);

                numToAppend = firstNum < secondNum ? firstNum : secondNum;  

                result += numToAppend.ToString () + " ";
            }
            writeFile (outputPath, result.TrimEnd ());
        }

        static string readFile (string input)
        {
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllText (input);
        }

        static void writeFile (string path, string contents)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText (path, contents);
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this method (reading from and writing to files) an effective and/or sensible way to deal with multi-line input? I find it more cumbersome when I am using the console.
2. Should a `StringBuilder` be used to append elements to string in this case?
3. Is the exercise of ignoring the first number, as I have done here, useful or useless in this context? I don't need to use that number, but should I?
4. This code is pretty long for such a small task. Is it more useful to write shorter code for such tasks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few methods that will make the task easier for you:

- [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to read the file line-by-line (see also [`File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx))
- [`Enumerable.Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.100).aspx) to skip the first line
- [`Enumerable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) to map the the lines to the minimum of the two numbers
- [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) for formatting the output

You might also consider taking the input and output file paths from the `args` parameter. Putting it all together (without error checking) could look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var minimums = File.ReadLines(args[0]).Skip(1).Select(GetMinimum);
    File.WriteAllText(args[1], string.Join(" ", minimums));
}

private static int GetMinimum(string line)
{
    var numbers = line.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    return Math.Min(numbers[0], numbers[1]);
}
```

I've been lazy here with error checking -- it would be a good exercise to add that to the code. It's also good practice to specify the file encoding when reading and writing files, which again I haven't shown here.

Comment: Can you please explain how to pass in the file through the `args` parameter?

Comment: @alanbuchanan If running the program from the command line, just type the file paths after the name of the executable: e.g. `MinimumOfTwo.exe /Users/rs/Dropbox/InputFile.txt /Users/rs/Dropbox/OutputFile.txt`. For Visual Studio, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3697320/1220238). For Xamarin, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024270/1220238).

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I think this is the first time I've seen `string[] args` actually made use of.

Comment: in the `GetMinimum` method, is it not suitable to simply use `return numbers.Min();` rather than listing the two array elements?

Comment: @alanbuchanan That's a good suggestion! That way you can also remove the call to `ToArray`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how the `Select (GetMinimum)` part works. How is it that you can call `GetMinimum` without passing a string?

Comment: @alanbuchanan the string is passed, just not explicitly -- `Select(GetMinimum)` is the same as `Select(line => GetMinimum(line))`.

Comment: WRT using `string[] args`: look into using [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) if you want to have "fancy" parameters and even a "help".

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a loop to concatenate strings it is always recommended to use a `StringBuilder` for the task. By using a `StringBuilder` you won't create a new string for each iteration.

---

> ```
> static string readFile (string input)
> ```

You should name the input parameter by its meaning. So better name it `fileName`.

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing. So `readFile()` -> `ReadFile()` and `writeFile()` -> `WriteFile()`

> ```
> static void writeFile (string path, string contents)
> ```

Here it should also be `fileName` instead of `path` and `content` instead of `contents`.

---

Instead `Convert.ToInt32()` I prefer `int.Parse()` or if I can't trust the given string to be a number I would use `int.TryParse()`

See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/199470/2655508

---

You could easily improve your code by replacing the tenary `numToAppend = firstNum < secondNum ? firstNum : secondNum;` by a simple `Math.Min()` call.

---

I would implement a method which is responsible for the parsing of the content of the file. This could return a `IEnumerable<T>` or a `List<T>` where I would prefer `T` to be a `Tuple<int,int>`.

Another method should then take this collection to evaluate the minimum of each `Tuple` and returns the result.

This would leave your `Main()` method to a call to

```
List<Tuple<int,int>> parseResults = ParseFile(inputPath);

string result = EvaluateMinimums(parseResults);

WriteFile (outputPath, result.TrimEnd());
```

This would be nice and clean and the implemented methods could be used for other similiar tasks in the future.

---

Ignoring the first number like you did, is maybe in this szenario ok, but in the long run you will need the number of tests. What I mean is, that for future problems to solve it maybe is needed to know this number, so implementing a method which evaluate the number of tests could be helpful.